# How to ignore a query field in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to ignore a field passed in a query? This issue is being caused by a query that is coming from an HTTP request.

For example this query would get all documents with title of `some title` and user's email of `user@example.com`

```
//From HTTP request
var query = {
    title: 'some title',
    'user.email': 'user@example.com'
};

somecollection.find(query, function(err,  documents) {
   //Not good because we know who posted these documents
});
```

The difficulty I'm having is that I'm working on an API that basically lets you pass a query to MongoDB and it returns the response. However, the part that is sensitive is that I don't want you to query by the user's email (because the document is supposed to be anonymous). I know you can limit the fields that are returned, but if you can query for all documents by `user@example.com` then those posts are no longer anonymous.

I guess I could try and delete that part of the query that is passed in from the HTTP request, but then I get into issues with someone using `$or` or any other operator that I don't know about or forget. Or if they use a string to access deeper parts of the user object.

Is there a way to limit what fields the query can query against?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to expose all of the query logic, then don't allow the client to pass in a query. Create a separate endpoint that only accepts the the title as search parameter.

That being said, you could easily retrofit this by doing something like.

```
var title_only_query = {
    'title': user_query.title
}
```

This way only the `title` property will be queried for.

Comment: Well I want to expose all the query logic ($or, $regex, etc), but I want it to ignore a field almost as if that field didn't exist in the DB. This might not be possible, but I want this as my goal is to keep most logic on the frontend without making a whole lot of custom backend code.

Comment: @Randy Yeah, you want to have the cake and eat it. Passing input directly to the database is a security no-no. You might want to read [the (very short) tale of Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) and think about it for a while.

Comment: You make a great point, but I don't _fully_ agree with that assertion. I'm passing it to the find function of Mongo. The query is already fully "escaped" - unlike original SQL queries. Point being is that it interacts with MongoDB exactly how I could ever expect - if you pass `user.email` it will query on that field. Regardless, it sounds like Mongo doesn't offer this kind of functionality, which in my case is a security concern and means I need to account for that. I appreciate your help though!